# How can i make a loop check for GID's from 20-60 with -ge and -le (bash script)

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I am having a bit of difficulty trying to make a bash script loop through my /etc/group file and echo those only with a GID between 20-60. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=/etc/group

while IFS=: read user x gid
do
echo " $gid - &user"
done < $filename
```

I am just starting to learn bash scripting and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: forgot the # in the !#/bin/bash and sorry about the format. Don't know why it didn't separate the lines

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash, it's easier to use arithmetic expressions (`(( ... ))`) as the conditional:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=/etc/group

while IFS=: read -r user _ gid _
do
    (( gid <= 20 && gid <= 60)) && echo " $gid - $user"
done < "$filename"
```

- Note the use of `_` to ignore fields that aren't of interest, which is a commonly used convention; since there may be more than 3 fields, having a trailing `_` is important, otherwise `$gid` would receive the entire *rest* of the input line.

  - Routinely using `-r` with `read` is a good habit to form to avoid unwanted interpretation of `\` chars. in the input.
- `(( ... ))` supports arithmetic expressions in the same way as [`$(( ... ))`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04), but is used as a *conditional* that interprets the calculation result as a *Boolean* that determines the outcome of the conditional.

  - That said, if you wanted to use `-ge` and `-le`, you could:

    - Using POSIX-compliant `[ ... ]` syntax<sup>[1]</sup>
      :
      `[ "$gid" -ge 20 ] && [ "$gid" -le 60 ]`
    - Using Bash syntax:
      `[[ $gid -ge 20 && $gid -le 60 ]]`

---

<sup>[1] `[ "$gid" -ge 20 -a "$gid" -le 60 ]` usually works too, but the `-a` and `-o` operators are considered *obsolescent*.</sup>